# Old versions of chaincode being run unintentionally

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-fabric

Old chaincode is being run even after I do the following:
1. stop and remove all docker containers with
    `docker stop $(docker ps -aq) && docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`
2. remove shared volume
    `sudo rm -r prod/`

After restarting the network I then try to install chaincode with the same chaincodeID and same version number as old network. Somehow the old chaincode that was deployed on the previous network gets instantiated instead of the new one. There must be some cache somewhere that I am not clearing. These are the volumes set in my `docker-compose.yaml` Any help would be great. Thanks

```
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - ../prod/peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have old images created for the chaincode not removed.

I personally run

```
docker rmi $(docker images |grep 'dev-peer')
```

to delete my dev peer imaegs which contain the chaincode before bringing up the network and when i dont want to change version of the chaincode. Try this out but it will remove EVERY image containing that dev-peer string! So when you have some images called the same way they are removed as well.

Comment: Ahh great! Thank you